# How to create a Rails project along with its database in Rails2?

Tags: grails-2.0, ruby-1.9.3, grails-2.3, grails-2.4, grails-2.2

I have the project built using

```
Rails 2.3.18
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
```

How to create the new project along with its Database.
Like in rails 4 & 5 we do

```
rails new app -d mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking over the guides for Rails 2.3 version here:
    http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/command_line.html

from this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/command_line.html it looks to be

```
rails commandsapp
```

Comment: Not given in the documentation to create a project along with the database.